# Password verification does not login just reloads login page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm ripping my noob hair out here. Can't understand why below code isn't working. The page loads alright, but when I try to log in with the username and password that is in my database the page is just reloaded to its original state with the login form, when I'd actually like to see a logout button instead. I've also tried comparing the password without salt and hash with an unhashed, unsalted equivalent in the database. Not working.

The only warnings I get are **"It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings."**, and I don't think those have anything to do with the password verification functionality.

The page starts out like this:

```
session_start();

error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Then follows some HTML. Then:

```
if (isset($_POST['log_out'])) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();
}
```

The logout button, when pressed, sets `$_POST['log_out']`. Then comes a function I got from a book, used to prevent SQL injection:

```
function mysql_fix_string($string) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
    $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    return $string;
}
```

Then comes the password verification part, which should only run if the user has submitted the login form (which posts back to the same page, thus setting `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`):

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $salt1 = 'how';
    $salt2 = 'pony';
    $password = md5($salt1 . $_POST['password'] . $salt2);

    $db_hostname = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $db_username = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $db_password = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $db_database = 'xxxxxxxxx';

    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

    if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($db_database)
        or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

    $username = mysql_fix_string($_POST['username']);

    $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = '" . $username . "'";

    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $passwordindatabase = $result['password'];

    if ($password == $passwordindatabase) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        unset($_POST['username']);
        unset($_POST['password']);
    }

}
```

A bit further down comes the login form, only shown `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true)`. It posts the values of the input fields `username` and `password` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (the same page).

Comment: Could you give a var_dump() of $passwordindatabase and $password? To check if they actually match or not?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Actually $password is string(32) "a18c15de5dbeb62f3bb78d4212bcc3b8" as expected, but $passwordindatabase is NULL. Obviously there's a problem here.

Comment: Are you sure the user you are using exists in the database? Also, do $username and $_POST['username'] match? That whole mysql_fix_string() might screw something up you hadnt intended. **Edit** Also make sure the table and fields you are referring to in your SQL statement are correct.

Comment: I would suggest `echo`ing your `$query` and running it directly against the database yourself to see what's wrong (maybe you got the column names wrong?). That or check the `mysql_error`.

Comment: Actually.. Not sure if this is it, but you might need to call mysql_query($query); Before you use mysql_fetch_assoc().. Actually, I'm quite sure that is it? :P

Comment: Tried everything suggested, last thing worked. Thanks again @Bono. I'm now a happy girl. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you're missing the [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function which means you aren't actually executing the query.

> mysql_query — Send a MySQL query

Do the following and see if it works:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

$passwordindatabase = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

**Edit**
On a completely different note, you should not use mysql functions since they are quite old fashioned and have mysql_injection vulnerability. I would advice you to start working with PDO as soon as possible, which (if done right) has got no mysql_injection vulerabilities.

Comment: +1 for the PDO bump :) Going to take a while for mysql* to die from the internet :(

Comment: @Cylindric What do you mean by your comment? Please explain to a noob ... :) (At least if it matters for my code.)

Comment: @JohannaLindh He means that everybody is using mysql functions these days even though it is not good practice to use it anymore, and that is why it will probaply take a while before mysql* dies from the interwebs, and that is a sad thing :( **edit** Oh, and no problem :P

Comment: @Bono Thanks. Actually, your solution only worked 90% of the way. (I could log in, but _any_ password worked.) The complete passage I have now and that is working is $result = mysql_query($query); $resultarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $passwordindatabase = $resultarray['password'];

Answer (score 0):

To use cookie-based sessions, `session_start()` must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

But, timezone warning is send before.

Set the timezone on `php.ini` file.

edited..
not only this problem. you must use `mysql_query()` function on sql request before `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's the problem here. session_start() is on top and worked fine on this page before I added the password verification functionality. (Had a static username and password before.)

Answer (score 0):

The only bit that "smells" about the code you're showing is this:

```
if ($password == $passwordindatabase) {
```

I'd prefer to see something like this:

```
if (strcmp($password, $passwordindatabase) == 0) {
```

Also we need to see the code where you're actually inserting the values into the `users` table, because clearly `$password` and `$passwordindatabase` aren't matching.

Comment: I did it "the ugly way": $salt1 = 'how'; $salt2 = 'pony'; $password = md5($salt1 . "qwerty" . $salt2); echo $password; Then copied what was echoed into an SQL insert query in my query browser. Just to have something to test on. The table users has three fields: id (autoincrementing integer), name, and password.